# how to access bean inside action in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have following test.jsp where i click on submit button and i am trying to set value in `transactionBean` in action and get it displayed on `HelloWorld.jsp`, but `getTransactionBean()` is returning null. Could you please let me know what am doing wrong.

**test.jsp**

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 - Login Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="displayActionlogmetoo.action" method="post">
    <s:submit method="logmetoo" key="login" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloWorld.jsp**

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

   username <s:property value="transactionBean.username"/>
   password <s:property value="transactionBean.password"/>

</body>
</html>
```

**My Struts.xml is:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>


<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default"> 
<action name="displayActionlogmetoo" 
    class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.DisplayLoginAction" 
    method="logmetoo">

<result name="success">HelloWorld.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**My Action is:**

```java
public class DisplayLoginAction extends ActionSupport {

   private TransactionBean transactionBean;
   public TransactionBean getTransactionBean() {
        return transactionBean;
   }

   public void setTransactionBean(TransactionBean transactionBean) {
        this.transactionBean = transactionBean;
   }

   public String logmetoo(){
        System.out.println("Inside logmetoo");
        getTransactionBean().setUsername("usename");
        getTransactionBean().setPassword("password");
        return SUCCESS;
   }
}
```

Comment: There's a couple of strange things in your code. First, your logmetoo method should return a string, like this: return Action.SUCCESS. This could be just a typo on your side. Secondly, on testjsp, your form action is "displayAction.action", but in your struts.xml there is no action with that name. I only see the action "displayActionlogmetoo". Maybe change your form tag too: <s:form action="displayActionlogmetoo" namespace="/">

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I made changes as suggested by you,but still I am getting NullPointerException in logmetoo method at getTransactionBean().setUsername("gaurav"); in Action class

Comment: You haven't initialized your `TransactionBean`, of course it is null.

Comment: Actually i was under impression that framework will initialize bean for me once it will look Action,so I was not instantiating it explicitly

Comment: It will if you submitting a form with this values, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two way of getting `transactionBean` instantiated:

1) Do it yourself. This is really simple:

```java
public String logmetoo(){
    System.out.println("Inside logmetoo");

    setTransactionBean(new TransactionBean());
    getTransactionBean().setUsername("gaurav");
    getTransactionBean().setPassword("bhardwaj");
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

2) Add input fields in your form and use the name attribute in to tell your action class it has to instantiate a field.

```jsp
<s:form action="displayActionlogmetoo.action" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="transactionBean.userName"/>
    <input type="text" name="transactionBean.password"/>
    <s:submit method="logmetoo" key="login" align="center" />
</s:form>
```

By submitting a form to the server, struts will automatically see

```jsp
name="transactionBean.userName"
```

and execute the following code:

```java
displayLoginAction.setTransactionBean(new TransactionBean());
displayLoginAction.getTransactionBean().setUserName(*whatever is filled in in the input*);
```

This is not magic, it is done by the param interceptor automatically for you. The param interceptor is part of the default-stack of interceptors.